# Print 3 Objects from the same class

Tags: c++

I started to read a book and at some point I came to `class` and after I created my first class and created in `main` an object, I decided to create two more Object on the same class. The program works fine but the Output seems to be different from my Understanding.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data{
    public:
        Data( string z ){
            cout << z << endl;
        }
        void setName ( string x ){
            name = x;
        }

        string getName( void ){
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string name;
};

int main ( void ){
    Data obj1( "Hello" );
    Data obj2( "World" );
    Data obj3( "!" );

    cout << obj3.getName() << endl;
    cout << obj2.getName() << endl;
    cout << obj1.getName() << endl;
}
```

And here is the Output:

```
Hello
World
!
```

But I thought it will print this:

```
!
World
Hello
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: You don't set `name` parameter anywhere. In constructor, you print constructors argument, which gives you your output, and then you use getName, which returns empty (uninitialized) string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output is created in your constructor, but you never set the name of the objects. That's why the order of the output appears in the order you created the objects.

I guess what you intended to do is this:

```
class Data{
public:
    Data( string z ){
        name = z;
    }
    void setName ( string x ){
        name = x;
    }

    string getName( void ){
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};
```

Comment: What example do you need Michi?

Comment: I understand now @TobiSH.